# How do I make Javascript (node.js) wait while I submit the form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, wait

I would like the program/script to stop/wait after "console.log ('3')" until you click "Finished!" (and prior download of data from the above form).
Clicking this button would be equivalent to restarting the program / script from "console.log ('4')".
How can this be achieved?

code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var helmet = require('helmet');
var rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const { title } = require('process');
 
const app = express(),
    { engine } = require('express-handlebars'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
 
app.use(express.static("public"));
 
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
 
//app.use(bodyParser({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.engine('handlebars', engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
 
async function readingFromForm() {
    console.log('data download has started');
    console.log('3');
    app.post('/added', function(sReq, sRes) {
        var newTitle = sReq.body.title;
        console.log('title:', newTitle);
 
        var newAuthor = sReq.body.author;
        console.log('author:', newAuthor);
 
        var newMood = sReq.body.mood;
        console.log('mood:', newMood);
 
        var newTime = sReq.body.time;
        console.log('time:', newTime);
 
        var newDate = sReq.body.date;
        console.log('date:', newDate);
 
        sRes.sendStatus(200);
 
        console.log(sReq); //Caution! It generates a lot of "spam" in the console !!!
        console.log(sRes); //Caution! It generates a lot of "spam" in the console !!!
 
    });
    console.log('4');
    console.log('data has been downloaded');
}
 
async function main() {
 
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://rafal:rafal@cluster0.gsf4h.mongodb.net/cattu?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
 
    const client = new MongoClient(uri);
 
    try {
        console.log('START');
        console.log('1');
        await client.connect(); // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
 
        console.log('2');
        await readingFromForm();
 
        console.log('5');
        await createListing(client, {
            title: "newTitle",
            author: "newAuthor",
            mood: "newMood",
            time: "newTime",
            date: "newDate" // YYYY-MM-DD
        })
        console.log('END');
 
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
 
        await client.close();
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);
async function createListing(client, newListing) {
 
    const result = await client.db("cattu").collection("test1").insertOne(newListing);
    console.log(`New listing created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
}
 
app.listen(port);
```

code in public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cattu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
 
<body>
 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="#form">Formularz</a></li>
    </ul>
 
    <div id="poraDnia">
        <div id="bgchange">
 
 
            <div class="main">
 
                <form method="POST" action="/added">
 
                    Podaj tytuł piosenki<br>
                    <input type="text" id="tytul" name="title" size="20px" required><br><br> Podaj wykonawcę<br>
                    <input type="text" id="wykonawca" name="author" size="20px" required><br><br> W jakim Jesteś nastroju?
                    <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="wesoly" value="wesoly" name="mood">
                    <label for="wesoly"> Wesoły/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="smutny" value="smutny" name="mood">
                    <label for="smutny"> Smutny/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="znudzony" value="znudzony" name="mood">
                    <label for="znudzony"> Znudzony/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="zmeczony" value="zmeczony" name="mood">
                    <label for="zmeczony"> Zmęczony/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="zdenerwowany" value="zdenerwowany" name="mood">
                    <label for="zdenerwowany"> Zdenerwowany/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="radosny" value="radosny" name="mood">
                    <label for="radosny"> Radosny/a </label><br>
 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="neutralny" value="neutralny" name="mood">
                    <label for="neutralny"> Neutralny/a </label><br>
 
                    <br>
 
                    <label for="pora"> Podaj porę dnia </label><br>
                    <select name="time" id="pora" required>
                        <option value="rano">Rano</option>
                        <option value="poludnie">Południe</option>
                        <option value="wieczor">Wieczór</option>
                        <option value="noc">Noc</option>
                        <option value="nie_pam">Nie pamiętam</option>
                    </select><br><br>
 
                    <label for="pora"> Podaj datę </label><br>
                    <input name="date" type="date"><br><br>
 
 
                    <button type="submit" class="submit">Skończone!</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="submit">Resetuj!</button>
 
                </form>
 
            </div>
 
            <div class="content">
 
                <div id="tlo3" onmouseover="rotatemoon(this)" onmouseout="rotatemoonB(this)">
                    <div id="obiekt_glowny3" onmouseover="movein(this)" onmouseout="moveout(this)">
                        <div id="ksiezyc_srodek"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tloGwiazdy1">
                    <div id="gwiazda1"></div>
                    <div id="gwiazda2"></div>
                    <div id="gwiazda3"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="tloGwiazdy2">
                    <div id="gwiazda11"></div>
                    <div id="gwiazda12"></div>
                    <div id="gwiazda13"></div>
                </div>
 
 
                <div id="tlo2">
                    <div id="obiekt_glowny2" onmouseover="bigSun(this)" onmouseout="smolSun(this)">
                        <div id="promien1"></div>
                        <div id="promien2"></div>
                        <div id="promien3"></div>
                        <div id="promien4"></div>
                        <div id="promien5"></div>
                        <div id="promien6"></div>
                        <div id="promien7"></div>
                        <div id="promien8"></div>
                        <div id="promien9"></div>
                        <div id="promien0"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 
                <div id="tlo1">
                    <div id="obiekt_glowny1">
                        <div id="slonce" onmouseover="blouClounds(this)" onmouseout="whiteClounds(this)">
                            <div id="promien11"></div>
                            <div id="promien12"></div>
                            <div id="promien13"></div>
                            <div id="promien14"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="chmura1"></div>
                    <div id="chmura2"></div>
                </div>
 
            </div>
 
            <div class="info1">
 
                <a href=""><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Zobacz pełną historię</a>
            </div>
            <div class="info2">
 
                <!-- Tutaj chcemy pobierać dane z bazy żeby móc je wyświetlić (pobierać może zewnętrzny skrypt) -->
                *Dane pobrane z bazy*
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you mix server and client side processing. When the user clicks "Skończone" that is when the complete form is sent to the server unless you stop the submit event

Comment: Seems like you need to understand code properly,  3 & 4 will be executed only once when application started while `app.post('/added', ...` is a routed which will be executed whenever form submitted that means multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to understand client-server communication, server should be ready to handle request whenever client made,

You may update your `readingFromForm` function to call `createListing` like

```
async function readingFromForm(client) {
    console.log('data download has started');
    console.log('3');
    app.post('/added', async function(sReq, sRes) {
        var bodyData = sReq.body;
        await createListing(client, bodyData);
        sRes.sendStatus(200);
        // sReq is an request object contains all request related information(data, objects & functions)
        // sRes is an response object contains all response related information(data, objects & functions)
 
    });
    console.log('4');
    console.log('data has been downloaded');
}
```

and in the `main` function, you need to pass `client` object to `readingFromForm` function like

```
 // await readingFromForm();
 await readingFromForm(client);
```

Comment: (1/2)
app.js:34
await createListing(client, bodyData);
         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)←[39m

Comment: (2/2)
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m

Node.js v17.4.0

Comment: updated code from `function(sReq, sRes) {` to `async function(sReq, sRes) {` so that we can use `await`

Answer (score 0):

use on click event handler in form. It will only submit the form when submit event will occur.

use onsubmit in form tag and an event handler in js.

Comment: This comment makes no sense.
Use the submit event handler to know when the user submits the form. But how will that block the server processing in any way?